# How to use a variable name in a formula instead of the column itself

Tags: r, variables, data.table, formula

I have data for which I would like to make a summary by group using the **summary_by** function (from the **doBy** package). I can't use the column names in the **summary_by** formula but variables I created before.
Below is the result I would like to achieve :

```
library(data.table)
library(doBy)

mtcars = data.table(mtcars)

doBy::summary_by(data = mtcars, mpg ~ gear + am, FUN = "mean")
```

output:

```
gear  am   mpg."mean"
3     0    16.10667
4     0    21.05000
4     1    26.27500
5     1    21.38000
```

Here is what I want to do :

```
library(data.table)
library(doBy)

mtcars = data.table(mtcars)

variable1 = "gear" # which is a column name of mtcars
variable2 = "am" # which is a column name of mtcars
variable3 = "mpg" # which is a column name of mtcars

doBy::summary_by(data = mtcars, variable3 ~ variable1 + variable2 , FUN = "mean")
```

I tried with the functions **get**, **assign**, **eval**, **mget** but I don't find the solution.

Comment: The function actually already exists in base R. `aggregate(mpg ~ gear + am, mtcars, mean)`.

Comment: I guess `get` should work : `doBy::summary_by(data = mtcars, get(variable3) ~ get(variable1) + get(variable2) , FUN = "mean")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide a string instead of a formula that relies on non-standard evaluation.

```
library(data.table)
library(doBy)

mtcars = data.table(mtcars)

variable1 = "gear" # which is a column name of mtcars
variable2 = "am" # which is a column name of mtcars
variable3 = "mpg" # which is a column name of mtcars

doBy::summary_by(data = mtcars, 
                 # alternatively to sprintf(), use paste() oder glue()
                 as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s + %s", variable3, variable1, variable2)), 
                 FUN = "mean")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @mnist it works !!

I just find 2 other ways :

```
library(data.table)
library(doBy)

mtcars = data.table(mtcars)

variable1 = "gear" # which is a column name of mtcars
variable2 = "am" # which is a column name of mtcars
variable3 = "mpg" # which is a column name of mtcars
```

- Summary_by solution with **reformulate** function :

  ```
  summary_by(data = mtcars, reformulate(
      termlabels = c(variable1, variable2),
      response = variable3)
  )
  ```
- **Datatable** native way :

  ```
  mtcars[, mean(get(variable3)), by = mget(c(variable1, variable2))]
  ```

Comment: Usually we use `reformulate()` when we want to construct a formula based on strings, or objects which are strings (as in your case), so I would say: "this is the way". All other ways are just workarounds (if the objective is to create a formula!).

Comment: Thanks for hinting to reformulate!